# Value Being Loaded As NULL to SQL Server When It Is A Zero And Other Than Zero It Is Working Fine via Informatica PowerCenter 10.1

Tags: sql-server, null, informatica, zero

I have come through a scenario where the value for a field is loading 'NULL' when actual value in the file is '0' but loading the correct value if the file has a non-zero value. I have used the debugger and read the session log. Everywhere the value is showing '0', but in the table it is loading as 'NULL'. Is this a known issue? Can anyone please help me overcoming this discrepancy.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try writing the output to a file and see the output ? Please give details of the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, Informatica has a special property which you can set when value is 0 or when value is null. 
Check that session property too. 
Check if there is anything present when value is 0.
Also, what is the column datatype which you are trying to populate too? Does that column have any constraint to not to accept "0"? check that too.

I agree (as @buzyjess says), writing the output to a text file will make it easy for debugging. So, please let us know how it looks like when you output to a file.

Comment: Are you writing to a numeric or a string target sql column?